# Looking for values in nested tuple

Tags: python

Say I have:

```
t = (
    ('dog', 'Dog'),
    ('cat', 'Cat'),
    ('fish', 'Fish'),
)
```

And I need to check if a value is in the first bit of the nested tuple (ie. the lowercase bits). How can I do this? The capitalised values do not matter really, I want to search for a string in only the lowercase values.

```
if 'fish' in t:
    print "Fish in t."
```

Doesn't work.

Is there a good way of doing this without doing a for loop with if statements?

Comment: I wish I could give you all the 'best answer'. Sorry, it has to go to someone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The elements of a tuple can be extracted by specifying an index: `('a', 'b')[0] == 'a'`. You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.0/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate over all elements of some *iterable*. A tuple is also iterable. Lastly, [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#any) tells whether any element in a given iterable evaluates to `True`. Putting all this together:

```
>>> t = (
...     ('dog', 'Dog'),
...     ('cat', 'Cat'),
...     ('fish', 'Fish'),
... )
>>> def contains(w, t):
...     return any(w == e[0] for e in t)
... 
>>> contains('fish', t)
True
>>> contains('dish', t)
False
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
any('fish' == tup[0] for tup in t)
```

EDIT: Stephan is right; fixed 'fish' == tup[0].  Also see his more complete answer.

Comment: That should be `==` instead of `in`, cause otherwise e.g. `"ish"` also matches.

Answer (score 3):

When you have an iterable of key-value pairs such as:

```
t = (
    ('dog', 'Dog'),
    ('cat', 'Cat'),
    ('fish', 'Fish'),
)
```

You can "cast" it to a dictionary using the [dict()](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) constructor, then use the `in` keyword.

```
if 'fish' in dict(t):
    print 'fish is in t'
```

This is very similar to the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144178/looking-for-values-in-nested-tuple/1144221#1144221).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
if 'fish' in (item[0] for item in t):
    print "Fish in t."
```

or this:

```
if any(item[0] == 'fish' for item in t):
    print "Fish in t."
```

If you don't care about the order but want to keep the association between `'dog'` and `'Dog'`, you may want to use a dictionary instead:

```
t = {
    'dog': 'Dog',
    'cat': 'Cat',
    'fish': 'Fish',
}

if 'fish' in t:
    print "Fish in t."
```